# fetch returning promise rather than value

Tags: promise, return-value, fetch

Hopefully the code below communicates the problem clearly. The issue is that in the module which uses the `get` method of `fetchData`, the value being returned is the actual Promise, rather than the JSON as desired. Any thoughts on this?

```
// fetchData.js module
var _ = require('lodash');


function get() {
  var endpoint1 = `/endpoint1`;
  var endpoint2 = `/endpoint2`;

  return fetch(endpoint1)
    .then((endpoint1Response) => {
      return endpoint1Response.json()
        .then((endpoint1JSON) => {
          return fetch(endpoint2)
            .then((endpoint2Response) => {
              return endpoint2Response.json()
                .then((endpoint2JSON) => {
                  var data = _.merge({}, {json1: endpoint1JSON}, {json2: endpoint2JSON});
                  console.log('data in fetch', data); // this logs the json
                  return data;
                });
            });
        });
    });
}

exports.get = get;

// module which uses get method of fetchData get
var fetchData = require('fetchData');
var data = fetchData.get();
console.log('returned from fetchData', data); // this logs a Promise
```

Comment: Of course it is, the only way to get the value is to access it inside the function passed to a Promise's `.then()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what's supposed to happen. The whole point of promises is that their result value is not immediately available and that doesn't change just because you're obtaining one from a separate module.

You can access the value like this:

```
var fetchData = require('fetchData');
fetchData.get().then(data =>
    console.log('returned from fetchData', data);
);
```

Also note that you are using promises in a non-idiomatic way and creating a "tower of doom." This is much easier on the eyes and accomplishes the same thing:

```
function fetchJson(endpoint) {
    return fetch(endpoint)
        .then(endpointResponse => endpointResponse.json()); 
}

function get() {
    var endpoint1 = `/endpoint1`;
    var endpoint2 = `/endpoint2`;

    return Promise.all([fetchJson(endpoint1), fetchJson(endpoint2)])
        .then(responses => {
            var data = { json1: responses[0], json2: responses[1] };
            console.log('data in fetch', data); // this logs the json
            return data;
        });
}
```

**Edit** I haven't used async/await in JavaScript, but to answer your question, I presume this would work:

```
async function fetchJson(endpoint) {
    var res = await fetch(endpoint);
    return res.json();
}

async function get() {
    var endpoint1 = `/endpoint1`;
    var endpoint2 = `/endpoint2`;

    var data = { 
        json1: await fetchJson(endpoint1), 
        json2: await fetchJson(endpoint2) 
    };

    console.log('data in fetch', data); // this logs the json

    return data;
}

// module which uses get method of fetchData get
async function main() {
    var fetchData = require('fetchData');
    var data = await fetchData.get();
    console.log('returned from fetchData', data);
}

return main();
```

Comment: Might there be a way to accomplish this with `async` and `await`?

Comment: @jerome Does the version of JavaScript you're using support async/await?

Comment: Yes it does. This is within a react native project, which supports some advanced JS features - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#content

Comment: @jerome I've added some code with async/await above that might work, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Thanks for steering me in the right direction on this. Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe you can `await` an `async` function outside of an `async` function. Meaning that at some point you *will* have to use `.then()`.

Comment: @idbehold I thought that might be the case. I've never used react, so I'm just guessing at what it allows. Edited my answer to something that seems more likely to be correct.